# Android: Camera Crash after taking landscape picture

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

I'm developing an android app that runs in portrait mode only.

In my activity I have a button that launches the `CameraActivity`.

If I take the picture in portrait mode, everything works as expected, the activity resumes and the picture is set in the `ImageView`.

But if I take pictures in landscape mode, I get a landscape picture (which is ok), but I'm losing the context and the app crashes (only on few devices like LG G4S).

As far as I have noticed, on this device the activity restarts instead of resuming. Did anyone know why is this happening only on some devices? Can anybody give me a solution to fix this problem?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{app.CustomFormScreenActivity}: 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String app.CustomFormSurvey.getParentId()' on a null object
>   reference.

The problem is that after taking the picture on this device, the activity restarts (instead of resuming) and I lose the Bundle (that's why the app throws NullPointerException).

Comment: show your Logcat for better understanding.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.CustomFormScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String app.CustomFormSurvey.getParentId()' on a null object reference. 

The problem is that after taking the picture on this device, the activity restarts (instead of resuming) and i lose the Bundle (thats why the app throws NullPointerException).

Comment: Are you using native camera?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the native camera

Answer (score 1):

in your manifest file put:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

under your activity tag.
Activity recreates on orientation change,so you need to handle it manually.